# Galera cluster not starting, wsrep issue

Tags: mariadb, digital-ocean, mysql-cluster, galera

I followed this tutorial (and read others as well) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04-servers
to install galera cluster with maria DB on Ubuntu 14.04 on DigitalOcean.
I used this repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main'
```

I configured everything properly but when I try to start the cluster invoking `sudo service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster` in the first node I have this error:

```
root@****:~# service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
start: invalid option: --wsrep-new-cluster
Try `start --help' for more information.
```

Am I missing anything?
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Check version of mariadb and galera -- wsrep-new-cluster is relatively new.

Comment: The problem was that! I installed the LEMP application and the other instance of mysql server was causing problem. I reset the droplet, install only Ubuntu 14.04 and everything worked fine! Thanks!!